# c# Binding on specific row in table

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

Using c# .net 2.0 ,  I want to bind a textbox to a specific row of my table. In Example :

```
 Table Person
 ID NAME PRENOM SPECIAL_CATEGORY
  1 BOB  BOB    mex
  2 AL   AL     tot
  3 PO   PO     pap
```

I want to bind my textbox on the field name where the row contains special_categeory = 'tot'.
Is it possible? or I need to create a Datarow for this row and binding it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Winforms and you have your data source as a component on your form already, this is fairly simple.

Drag a new `BindingSource` onto your form and set its data source to be whatever your existing data source is. You can then specify a filtering expression in the new `BindingSource`'s `Filter` property in the designer. Bind your `TextBox` to your new `BindingSource` and you're all set.

Doing this manually (without the designer) is only marginally more complicated.

```
BindingSource newSource = new BindingSource();

newSource.DataSource = yourExistingDataSource;
newSource.Filter = "special_categeory = 'tot'";

textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", newSource, "DataMember");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind via...

```
myNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add( "Text", MyTable, "NAME" );
myPrenomTextBox.DataBindings.Add( "Text", MyTable, "PRENOM" );
mySpecial_CategoryTextBox.DataBindings.Add( "Text", MyTable, "SPECIAL_CATEGORY" );
```

I actually have a framework that scrolls through all controls, and if they match a column name in a given table, they immediately bind themselves like above.

Then, when you scroll the grid, it should also refresh the individual text controls in your form too.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in data binding designer for this? This also doesn't filter the results as required.

Answer (score -1):

If there is some binding that needs to be done, you can follow this pattern:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(MyTable);
dv.RowFilter = "SPECIAL_CATEGORY = 'tot'";
GridView1.DataSource = dv;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But I don't think you bind to a TextBox?  You can set the Text property like:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in MyTable.Rows)
{
    if (dr["SPECIAL_CATEGORY"] != DBNull.Value &&
          dr["SPECIAL_CATEGORY"].ToString() == "tot")
    {
       myTextBox.Text = dr["NAME"].ToString()
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume it's Winforms and this is how you can do it:

```
myTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SPECIAL_CATEGORY = 'tot'";
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",myTable.DefaultView,"Name");
```

Comment: -1. This source is being used for a grid (you're assuming it's a DataTable or DataView) and you're now filtering the contents of the grid just to get the TextBox. A new source pointing to the same data should be used rather than modifying the existing source.

Comment: How do you know the source is being used for a grid? The OP never specified the Table is being bound to anything else....

Comment: Good point. Nonetheless, you should NOT modify the properties on the DefaultView. There's no reason to do that. If you want to stick with the classic ADO.NET data objects, create a new DataView on that table and filter on that.